# For loop data in picker - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, picker

How to make for loop with which get all data in picker with corresponding label and values?

For example I have two connected pickers. In first picker I have all tool_names in my database. In second picker I have all tool_count for corresponding tool_name.

How when I click on first picker and select label in second picker automatically get tool_count for corresponding tool_name and can edit this value (tool_count) with increasing and decreasing?

I will be very thankful if you help me and if you can explain in more details.